CORS in nestjs and react app after containerization
I use nestjs as backend and enabled cors via
  app.enableCors();

Backed runs on localhost:3001
In frontend I use react, which runs in localhost:3000 and it sends request to localhost:3001
When I run it locally in mac os, there are no cors problems. My browser developer tools > request initiator shows only localhost as basepath. However when I run everything in remote instance (Debian 11) I face with cors error and my request innitiator shows first localhost, then ip-adress of instance
my docker-compose file looks as follows:
version: '3.9'

services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres
    container_name: postgres_db
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: ${POSTGRES_DB}
      POSTGRES_USER: ${POSTGRES_USER}
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  app:
    build:
        context: .
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
    environment:
        - API_KEY=${API_KEY}
    ports:
        - '3001:3001'
    depends_on:
        - postgres
    volumes:
        - ./src:/app/src
  front:
    build:
        context: ../tickets-admin-front/frontend/.
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
        - '3000:3000'

volumes:
  postgres_data:

Seems like docker engine on mac os and remote debian 11 instance are configured somehow differently
I want to fix cors and run everything through docker-compose

What CORS error? Edit your question and add the error message (as text).

I solved the issue. The problem is that when in frontend I wanted to send request to localhost:3001 (backend and frontend were located on the same server), it could not somehow find that backend server. But when changed the localhost to ip address, it has found immediately. I found that weird, or do I misunderstand something in Linux networking
